# Update multiple rows in the target table from one row in the source table using a natural key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to update two columns in a FACT table using data from a    dimension table. the challenge is that I don't have a primary key that match both tables, so I have to use a natural key, two columns to create a unique value. besides the source have a single record and the target has multiples records. if I do a merge I get

> ora-30926 unable to get a stable set of rows

and if I do an update I get another  error. please I need help.

I try this update statement:

```
UPDATE dw.target_table obc
SET
( obc.sail_key,
  obc.durations ) = (
    SELECT 
        sd.sail_key,
        sd.durations
    FROM
        dw.source_table sd
    WHERE
        obc.code_1 = sd.code_2
        AND obc.date_1 = sd.date_2
)
WHERE
obc.item NOT IN (
    30,
    40
)
AND obc.sail_key = 0
and OBC.load_date between to_date('01-12-2018','DD-MM-YYYY') 
AND  to_date ('31-12-2018','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

and I try this merge statement:

```
   MERGE INTO dw.target_table obc 
  USING ( SELECT distinct
                  code_2,date_2,durations,sail_key
          FROM dw.source_table
   ) tb_dim 
  ON ( obc.code_1 = tb_dim.code_2
  AND obc.date_1 = tb_dim.date_2 )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET obc.durations = tb_dim.durations,
  obc.sail_key = tb_dim.sail_key
 WHERE
obc.sail_key = 0
AND obc. NOT IN (
    30,
    40
)
AND obc.loaddate BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2012','DD-MM-YYYY') 
AND TO_DATE  ('31-01-2012','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: Your MERGE example swapped role of `dw.target_table` and `dw.source_table` compared to the UPDATE example. I have edited the MERGE sample to make sense. For future reference, when redacting code please take care to ensure the finished product is consistent and coherent. What you post is all we have to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ora-30926 unable to get a stable set of rows

This means `(code_2,date_2)` is **not** a unique key of `tb_dim`. Consequently your USING subquery does not produce a set which matches just one row to any row in  `obc`. Consequently the MERGE fails, because Oracle cannot determine which row from the USING subquery should be applied to the target. The DISTINCT does not help because it is applied to the whole projection and it seems you have multiple different values of `durations,sail_key` for each permutation of `code_2,date_2`.

You don't say which error you get when you run your UPDATE but presumably it's ORA-01779 or ORA-01427. Something indicating the subquery isn't returning a set of joining keys.

So how do you fix the situation? We cannot give you the correct solution because this is a failure of your data model or your specification. Solving requires an understanding of your business that we do not have. But generally you need to find an extra rule which reduces the USING subquery to a set. That is:

- add a third key column which allows the ON clause to map one row in `tb_dim` to one row in `obc`; or
- use `row_number()` analytic function in the subquery to fake such a column, preferably ordering by a meaningful column such as date; or
- add a criterion WHERE clause of the subquery to remove duplicate values of `code_2,date_2`.

Alternatively, if you don't care which particular values of `durations,sail_key` get applied you can use an aggregate:

```
USING (SELECT code_2
              ,date_2
              ,max(durations) as durations
              ,max(sail_key) as sail_key
       FROM dw.source_table
       group by code_2,date_2 ) tb_dim
```

Use whatever function makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice !